# How can I get my email to go to Gmail and my hosted server?

Tags: email, dns, gmail

I've switched my main domain to point the MX to Google Apps, and my actual domain's server with the lowest MX priority. My idea is to have my primary emails on Google Apps, where the secondary are via Cpanel. Is this even possible?

Currently MX records read:

```
0 Google
4 Google
4 Google
9 Google
9 Google
10 My server
```

I have X@domain.com which is added in G. Apps, and B@domain.com which is only added in cpanel.

Is there anyway to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MX records work this way. When a mail is delivered it will look at your MX server that has the lowest priority, and it will only go to the next priority server if the first one is not `online` and `responding`. Now this is the `only` way it is designed to work. So imho you won't be able to achieve what you want this way.

Now looking at your question, adding your host's email id as forwarding address to your gmail account will send a copy to your host's id. Isn't this the easiest solution?

Comment: Probably. I asked because I have quite a few forwarders that are just that, only forwarders. Not to mention, the unlimited capability. I suppose I could just forward to another domain I own which isn't on Gmail if I needed the backup.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you create email address on subdomain (example@sub.domain.com) and add NS record for cPanel's DNS server or MX record for cPanel's mail server - no, you can't do it. Furthermore, if you admix your MX servers into pool for Google Apps it could have some bad effect on mail routing.